# Equally distribute points on a rectangle on a map (debugging)

Tags: php, debugging, dictionary, leaflet

I want to distribute N points equally on a map by generating latitudes and longitudes. I is for a leaflet based web map to display features which do not have a geographical representation.

The points should be in the gray rectangle on top of Tchad (sorry Tchad).

[image]

Unfortunately the markers end up wrong.

I have the following code and I am sure I mixed latitude and longitude somewhere, but can't find where.

(PS: also I think the final code is useful for anybody who wants to accomplish the same task - to simply distribute points in a rectangle)

This is my function:

```
function distribute_points()
{
    $articles = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'lang' => 'en',
        )
    );

    // consts
    $colsToRowsFactor = 5;
    $minLat = 23.40; // x
    $minLon = 16.8;  // y
    $maxLat = 4.8;
    $maxLon = 20.9;

    $lonRange = $maxLon - $minLon;
    $latRange = $maxLat - $minLat;

    $count = count($articles);

    $cols = ceil( sqrt($count / $colsToRowsFactor));

    $maxRows = ceil($count / $cols);

    $lonIncrement = $lonRange / $cols;
    $latIncrement = $latRange / $maxRows;
    $i = 0;

    $lat = $minLat;
    $lon = $minLon;
    foreach ($articles as $article) {
        $i++;
        echo $article->ID . ' ' . $article->post_title . ' ' . $lat . ' ' . $lon . PHP_EOL; //...


        $lat += $latIncrement;

        if ($i % $maxRows == 0) {
            $lat = $minLat;
            $lon += $lonIncrement;
            echo '---------' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        $field_obj = get_field_object(
            'location',
            $article->ID,
            array(
                'load_value' => true
            )
        );

        $value = $this->makeGeoJson( $lat, $lon );

        update_field('location', $value, $article->ID);
    }

}
```

Of minor importance

```
    /**
     * @param $lat
     * @param $lon
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function makeGeoJson( $lat, $lon ) {
        return <<<JSON
{  
   "zoom_level":0,
   "center":{  
      "lat":59.83598558292964,
      "lng":-154.68749999999997
   },
   "markers":{  
      "m_31":{  
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties":{  
        "popupContent":""
     },
     "geometry":{  
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[  
           $lat,
           $lon
        ]
     },
     "id":31
      }
   },
   "bounds":null,
   "initial_bounds":{  
      "_southWest":{  
     "lat":2.39,
     "lng":-25.73
      },
      "_northEast":{  
     "lat":24.93,
     "lng":16.1
      }
   },
   "drawnItems":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[]}

}
JSON;
    }

}
```

Update: switching lat and lon in the geo Json kind of works, but why? I thought GeoJSON uses lat,lon order?

```
function distribute_points()
{
    $articles = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'lang' => 'en',
        )
    );

    // consts
    $colsToRowsFactor = 5;
    $minLat = 23.40; // x
    $minLon = 16.8;  // y
    $maxLat = 4.8;
    $maxLon = 20.9;

    $lonRange = $maxLon - $minLon;
    $latRange = $maxLat - $minLat;

    $count = count($articles);

    $cols = ceil( sqrt($count / $colsToRowsFactor));

    $maxRows = ceil($count / $cols);

    $lonIncrement = $lonRange / $cols;
    $latIncrement = $latRange / $maxRows;

    $minLat += ($latIncrement / 2);
    $lat = $minLat;
    $lon = $minLon;

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($articles as $article) {
        echo $article->ID . ' ' . $article->post_title . ' ' . $lat . ' ' . $lon . PHP_EOL; //...

        if ($i != 0 && $i % $maxRows == 0) {
            $lat = $minLat;
            $lon += $lonIncrement;
            echo '---------' . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $lat += $latIncrement;
        }

        $value = $this->makeGeoJson( $lon, $lat ); // switched lon and lat works, but why?

        update_field('location', $value, $article->ID);

        $i++;

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "kind of works"?

Comment: Means then points end up in the rectangle. But I do not understand why cause I think geojson should have lat,long order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that GeoJSON uses a [longitude, latitude, elevation] order. This is why it works when you switch latitude and longitude.
Below is from [this](https://macwright.org/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite.html) website.

## Position

A [position](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions) is an array of coordinates in order: this is the smallest unit that we can really consider ‘a place’ since it can represent a point on earth. GeoJSON describes an order for coordinates: they should go, in order:

`[longitude, latitude, elevation]`
This order can be surprising. Historically, the order of coordinates is usually “latitude, longitude”, and many people will assume that this is the case universally. Long hours have been wasted discussing which is better, but for this discussion, I’ll summarize as such:

- longitude, latitude matches the X, Y order of math
- data formats usually use longitude, latitude order
- applications have tended to use latitude, longitude order

Here’s a [handy chart of what uses which ordering.](https://www.macwright.org/lonlat/)